# Why are finance costs excluded in capital budgeting?

Tags: present-value, capital-budget

I am having trouble understanding why finance costs are excluded while calculating cash flows of a project. My teacher says that the discounting at the required rate already incorporates the effect of finance costs so it would result in double counting.

This is what I have trouble understanding:

Say the value of investment
(Initial cash outflow)     = 1,000,000

The finance cost
(i.e, the interest rate) = 10%

Finance cost per year = 100,000

Assuming equal cash flows of 250000 per annum for 5 years,

The present value of the 1st year cash flow = 227,250
(250,000 * 0.909)

Which considers a finance cost of only 22,750 and not 90,900(100,000 * 0.909)

Answer (score 1):

22,750 is not the "finance cost". If your "annual cash flow" of 250k is net, meaning it includes the revenues *and* expenses of the project, then it includes the 100k of "interest" you would pay if you borrowed the money at 10% (meaning that the gross revenue is 350k). It might also include cash flow to pay down the loan, depending on how the loan was structured. But from a DCF point a view, you discount the total net cash flow at each period using a single discount rate (you don't discount loan payments differently that revenues, for example).

Your teacher is not confusing you with those details, just giving you the total net cash flow, which implicitly includes loan interest (if any).

But don't assume that "discount rate" is completely analogous to "finance cost". There are many other factors that go into the discount rate, including the risk of the project (e.g. what's the probability of the project failing, or what's the potential range of cash flows) that go into the discount rate. Other types of analysis use "required rate of return" for the discount rate, which would be higher than a risk-free interest rate.

If the project were completely risk-free, *then* the discount rate should be equal to the interest rate you'd get from putting the money in a savings account or other risk-free investment (e.g. money market funds or CD), which would be a lower rate than what you could borrow the money for.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but most of the problems we've solved so far provided us with the initial cash outflow, the number of units of a product sold during the years and a few variable and fixed expense s incurred and of course the cost of finance. Hence, we were asked to calculate the net cash flow during the year and then discount it. In all of the problems we didn't deduct the finance cost seperately. We were told that it would be considered while discounting so there was no need to deduct it seperately. What are your views on this?